# Filter all mails sent to domain except for specific recipient

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

How can I filter all the messages sent to `*@domain.com` except for those sent **exclusively** to `user@domain.com`?

I tried `to:domain.com AND -to:user@domain.com` and `to:(domain.com -user@domain.com)` but it shows all the messages sent to `*@domain.com` that do not have `user@domain.com` as the recipient.

Answer (score 8):

Was playing around with Gmail search. The syntax for what you want is as follows:

```
to:*@domain.com -to:user@domain.com
```

This also works for the "from" section as well, so it's good if you want to filter out unwanted sales and promo emails.

Comment: The asterisk isn't required.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I never really checked, and assumed that the asterisk was needed, considering it's widespread use as an identifier for "anything goes here".

Comment: This also works as a stored Filter, except you need to remove the leading "to:" or "from:" so for example `*@domain.com -user@domain.com` works as a stored filter.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want to do isn't currently possible in Gmail. You need a search operator like `only` or `exclude`, neither of which are among Gmail's [list of operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190).

It would be a nice feature to have; perhaps someone will develop a Gmail add-on with that capability.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by first creating a Label and a Filter for the user in which you do not want to see emails to.

1. Go to settings
2. Filters and Blocked Addresses
3. Create a new filter
4. Put the users email address in the To field
5. In the bottom right click `Create filter with this search`
6. Tick `Apply the label` - `New Label...`
7. Tick `Also apply filter to X matching conversations`
8. Create filter

Now all emails to that user will have a label attached to them.

For your search query:
`to:domain -is:LabelCreatedAbove`

Just note that is your label has spaces like this `I am a label` the spaces will convert to `-` in the search box: `I-am-a-label`

Comment: But it still adds label to all messages sent to the user regardless of whether the user is the only recipient or not.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is searching for a multi-domain automatic filter with one specific email excluded, Ben's answer could be extended to this:

`{*@domain-one.com, *@domain-two.com} -user@domain-one.com`